# How to Reference using non-ID fields in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Bear with me, this is a legacy system, so the table relations are not idea.

Dog has field ID, Owner, and Name

DogHouse has ID, Owner and Name.  It does not have a foreign key reference to Dog.  Rather, it is related by Owner and Name.

In my DogMap, I need to be able to tell it how to reference its Doghouse.  How do I do that?  When I try

```
  Reference(x=>x.DogHouse).
```

What do I put after the dot?  It's not ID, and should be Owner and Name.

Answer (score 3):

non id fields must be one property

```
Reference(x=> x.DogHouse, "Owner").PropertyRef(house => house.Owner).Readonly();
```

since both are needed we have to use some tricks

```
DogHouse FakeReferenceProp { get; set; }
public DogHouseMap()
{
    Component(x => FakeReferenceProp, c =>
    {
        c.Map(x => x.Owner, "Owner").Readonly();
        c.Map(x => x.Name, "Name").Readonly();
    });
}

// in DogMap
Reference(x=> x.DogHouse).Columns.Add("Owner", "Name").PropertyRef(house => FakeReferenceProp).Readonly();
```